# how to add comma <input> value in id=price2

Tags: php, html

I am a beginner and I have a basic question,

I have code like this

```html
<input type="text" name="price1" id="price1">
<input type="text" name="price2" id="number_format(price2, 0, "", ".");">
```

and it will display :
2000000

what I want is  display price1 2000000 and  display price2 2.000.000

but still can't

please help , and many thanks

Comment: You are formattig the ID of a HTML element, I doubt that you want to do this, are you trying to set the `value` instead? Number only IDs are imho not a good idea

Answer (score 0):

You can not do this like you are doing,

you need to declare a PHP variable like

```
$input_id = here what ever you want to store in it;
```

and than

```
<input type="text" name="price1" id="price1">
<input type="text" name="price2" id="<?= $input_id ?>">
```

you can also use an other programming language to do this..

you want a dynamic ID .... the above example will provide you a good result